# dojo filteringSelect - allow entry of list items only

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to force filteringselect to only allow the user to type items that appear in the drop list. I know that it will invalidate anything that is not in the list, but I would just rather it not allow invalid entries to show.
Really, what I would like to see is behaviour that matches the HTML SELECT control. Dojo doesnt seem to provide this with any of its controls.

Comment: Any luck on getting a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I read you okay but this is how it things go:

- If you type what is in the drop list of the FilteringSelect widget
  then there will be no validation error.
- If you want to match the HTML Select dropdown, then use
  `dijit.form.Select`.
- If you want to Filtering Select behaviour but want also be able to type in values that are not in the drop list, then use the
  `dijit.form.ComboBox` widget.

Comment: from my experience, dijit.form.Select doesn't match the behaviour of HTML SELECT - it has no provision for typing a selection